# Fast data.table subsetting with multiple exclusion criteria

Tags: r, data.table

I am working on a piece of code that needs to iterate many times. I have used `profvis` to trace the bottleneck to a single call that is ~100x slower than any other line:

`outcomes_dt[outcome_1 != exclude & outcome_2 != exclude & outcome_3 != exclude]`

This is a very large data.table (already keyed on `outcome_1`,`outcome_2`,`outcome_3`). The motivation for the code is that you have an "observation", and then you exclude that observation from the table of all potential observations. Here would be a fully reproducible example:

```
exp_keys <- c(letters,LETTERS,month.name)
outcomes_dt <- data.table(outcome_1 = rep(exp_keys, each = 64*64),outcome_2 = rep(rep(exp_keys, each = 64), 64),outcome_3 = rep(exp_keys,64*64), value = 1:(64*64))
setkeyv(outcomes_dt, c("outcome_1","outcome_2","outcome_3"))
exclude <- "a"
outcomes_dt[outcome_1 != exclude & outcome_2 != exclude & outcome_3 != exclude]
```

Are there any faster options for the last line, especially any that take advantage of keying?

```
microbenchmark(
  "keyed" = outcomes_dt[data.table(exclude,exclude,exclude)], #find one row
  "keyed_exc" = outcomes_dt[!data.table(exclude,exclude,exclude)], #exclude one row
  "keyed_single" = outcomes_dt[data.table(exclude)], #find all occurrences in column 1
  "keyed_exc_single" = outcomes_dt[!data.table(exclude)], #exclude all occurances in column 1
  "filtered_1" = outcomes_dt[outcome_1 != exclude & outcome_2 != exclude & outcome_3 != exclude], # filter option 1 (Bottleneck)
  "filtered_2" = outcomes_dt[!(outcome_1 == exclude | outcome_2 == exclude | outcome_3 == exclude)], # alternative filter
  "chained" = outcomes_dt[outcome_1 != exclude][outcome_2 != exclude][outcome_3 != exclude], # chained
  "exclude_keys" = outcomes_dt[data.table(exp_keys[2:64])] # pre-filter the key
)
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min        lq       mean     median         uq      max neval
            keyed  2.201301  3.291002   4.347171   3.858901   4.978051  14.9554   100
        keyed_exc 22.536301 31.464652  43.713268  35.506901  51.614801 184.8499   100
     keyed_single  2.545301  3.599850   4.607506   4.216601   5.199201  10.9757   100
 keyed_exc_single 23.042200 30.461651  37.625179  34.187701  41.726401  80.6452   100
       filtered_1 30.460302 42.361101  58.039301  48.205951  68.223401 238.8149   100 # CAN THIS BE IMPROVED
       filtered_2 38.597800 45.118002  57.723060  52.782100  65.944351 181.1115   100 
          chained 69.779000 93.019601 114.897401 105.665200 123.846851 263.9510   100
     exclude_keys 27.473900 34.473251  43.897457  38.198352  46.258451 227.0823   100
```

I know these are not all equivalent, but I am hoping for a speed improvement similar to the "keyed" approach (which is much simpler)

Comment: doesnt improve your toy example but sometimes chaining can be faster than a single but complex logical expression. Compare `outcomes_dt[outcome_1 == exclude & outcome_2 != exclude & outcome_3 != exclude]` to `outcomes_dt[outcome_1 == exclude][outcome_2 != exclude][outcome_3 != exclude]`. Especially if one expression simplifies your data significantly

Comment: @mnist From the question, OP wants `!=` not `==` condition for all three outcomes, in which case the chained version doesn't exactly improve performance (not in my environment anyway).

Comment: exactely, thats why I introduced the comment with "doesnt improve your toy example" and didnt propose it as a solution, just as a way that helped me in such settings

Comment: Added to benchmark - as you point out it is not faster, but appreciate the recommendation nonetheless

Comment: Hi @Chris. I haven't tried your code, but I note that for "keyed" and "keyed_exc" you have commented "#find one row" and "#exclude one row", respectively. I think the code selects _all_ rows (excludes _all_ rows) according to the condition in `i`. It feels like I have misunderstood your issue :) See also [the vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-keys-fast-subset.html), section "c) Keys and multiple columns".

Comment: @Henrik you are right that it would select all rows that meet that condition, but based on how the scenario matrix is set up, it would practically only be 1 row because only one row has 1 and 2 and 3 == excude